# Asp.net and Sql Server Jquery autocomplate data binding

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

As you can see there is a selectbox. I want to pull data from ms sql database via asp net, but I have no idea how to do it. The design code is as follows;

```
    <div class="form-group">
<label class="form-label">Basics</label> 
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon">
<i class="fa fa-globe"></i> 
</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type for Suggestions" id="typeahead-1">
</div> 
</div>
```

In the Jquery script code:

```
var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];
$('#typeahead-1').typeahead({
hint: true,
highlight: true,
minLength: 1
}, {
name: 'states',
displayKey: 'value',
source: substringMatcher(states)
});
```

[İmage for design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcrTi.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link

http://www.encodedna.com/jquery/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-ajax-example-with-webapi.htm

```
$('#typeahead-1').typeahead({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/Country/" + request,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                var arrCountry = [];
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    arrCountry.push(item.CountryName);
                }))
                response(arrCountry);                      
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    },
    hint: true,             
    highlight: true,       
    minLength: 1            
});
```

Comment: The data type is not json. I am taking data with a normal DataReader.

Comment: For that you can convert your dataReader Data to json format in Asp.Net code

Comment: Or you can convert your data to list or array.

Comment: Are there any resources related to this topic

Comment: Refer this link..It may help you... http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/871114/Bootstrap-TypeAhead-AutoComplete-textbox-from-Database-in-ASPNet/

Comment: I finished Json. I wrote your first script. Now, however, it gives a "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main" error.

Comment: Can you provide your code which you have tried? Or any jsfiddle for the same